# Android SharedPreferences String Set - some items are removed after app restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I save a string set in the shared preferences, if I read it out it's ok. I start other activities, go back and read it again, it's ok. If I close the application, and start it again, I get the set, but with only 1 item instead of 4. It happens all the time. Is there a known issue? What could I do wrong?

In a class, what is created in the application's oncreate method I have a SharedPreferences and a SharePreferences.Editor variable. I use them in the save and load methods.

```
public void saveFeedback(FeedbackItem feedbackItem) {
    checkSp();
    Set<String> feedbackSet = getFeedbacksSet();
    if(feedbackSet == null){
        feedbackSet = new HashSet<String>();
    }
    JSONObject json = createJSONObjectfromFeedback(feedbackItem);
    feedbackSet.add(json.toString());
    ed.putStringSet(CoreSetup.KEY_FEEDBACK, feedbackSet);
    ed.commit();
}

public Set<String> getFeedbacksSet(){
    checkSp();
    Set<String> ret = sp.getStringSet(CoreSetup.KEY_FEEDBACK, null);
    return ret;
}

private void checkSp(){
    if(this.sp == null)
        this.sp = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(applicationContext.getPackageName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(this.ed == null)
        this.ed = this.sp.edit();
}
```

I just can't understand how could it happen, to store perfectly all items while the app is running, then after a restart not all items are in the set. And I think if all items are removed it could be more acceptable than some items are gone, and one item is still there. Is there an explanation?

Comment: Where you store the values?

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code adding multiple items to feedbackSet. So the returned set contains only single set as per your code.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja
Please read the code again.
In the saveFeedback method, I add a feedbackitem to to set.
In my test, I writed 4 feedbacks (write 1 feedback, add to set... x4)
So if you call the saveFeedback method 4 times, it adds 4 feedback items to the set...

Comment: @Gunaseelan In SharedPreferences... the key is the CoreSetup.KEY_FEEDBACK, the type is StringSet. Or what is your question?

Comment: That is wrong. It will not add 4 feedback items to the set. You will need to add 4 items first and then commit. Otherwise your last feedback will be overwritten by the latest written feedback. You need to move commit out of that function and call it separately after 4 feedbacks have been added to the set.

Comment: @MadhurAhuja
Please read the code again.
the method does the following:
- get StringSet from Preferences
- add an item to it
- save the StringSet to Preferences

if I call this 4 time it should add 4 item to it

Comment: Are your all 4 feedbacks unique? It will only add the items to the set only if its not already present.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41087/discussion-between-madhur-ahuja-and-user2313423)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Based on your question, you should call commit only after 4 items have been added to the set. 
In your code, you are calling commit for each feedback which will overwrite the previous feedback.

**Update**: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet(java.lang.String, java.util.Set)

`Note that you must not modify the set instance returned by this call. The consistency of the stored data is not guaranteed if you do, nor is your ability to modify the instance at all.`

This is exactly what you are doing

Comment: Please read the code again. the method does the following: - get StringSet from Preferences - add an item to it - save the StringSet to Preferences if. I call this 4 times it should add 4 item to it

Comment: Thanks for the point! Wrapping it like this solved the problem: new HashSet<>(mPrefs.getStringSet(KEY, new HashSet<String>()));

Comment: Such weird behaviour... copying the items to a new Set did the trick

Answer (score 22):

This "problem" is documented on  [`SharedPreferences.getStringSet()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getStringSet%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Set%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29).

getStringSet() returns a reference of the stored HashSet object inside SharedPreferences. When you add elements to this object, they are added in fact *inside* SharedPreferences.

The workaround is making a copy of the returned Set and putting the new Set into SharedPreferences. I tested it and it works.

In Kotlin, that would be

```
    val setFromSharedPreferences = sharedPreferences.getStringSet("key", mutableSetOf())
    val copyOfSet = setFromSharedPreferences.toMutableSet()
    copyOfSet.add(addedString)

    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putStringSet("key", copyOfSet)
    editor.apply() // or commit() if really needed
```

Comment: _When you add elements to this object, they are added in fact inside the SharedPreferences._ So.. in order to add elements to `Set<>` inside SharPref I don't have to `apply()` them?

Comment: What a quick glance to the android source code reveals is that. When you putStringSet() it makes a copy of that and also marks it as modified. But when you getStringSet() it and just modify it, it won't be marked as modified, so apply or commit will not write it to disk. And hence when your app is restarted, the data won't reflect your changes. (and I guess the data changed callback won't be called either)

Answer (score 9):

Try to create Copy of your set, and than you can save it in same prefs:

```
private Set<String> _setFromPrefs;


public void GetSetFromPrefs()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    Set<String> someSets = sharedPref.getStringSet("some_sets", new HashSet<String>() );
    _setFromPrefs = new HashSet<>(someSets); // THIS LINE CREATE A COPY
}


public void SaveSetsInPrefs()
{
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putStringSet("some_sets", _setFromPrefs);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Thank you your below 2 lines helped me. 


    Set<String> someSets = sharedPref.getStringSet("some_sets", new HashSet<String>() );
    


     _setFromPrefs = new HashSet<>(someSets); // THIS LINE CREATE A COPY

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same problem. Solved it by clearing the editor after instantiating and before committing.

```
sPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    sFavList = sPrefs.getStringSet(context.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_fav_key), null);
    sEditor = sPrefs.edit();
    sEditor.clear(); // added clear, now Set data persists as expected
    if (sFavList == null) sFavList = new HashSet<>();
    sFavList.add(title);
    sEditor.putStringSet(context.getResources().getString(R.string.pref_fav_key), sFavList).apply();
```

I tried creating a copy as others suggested, but that didn't work for me.

Found this solution [here](https://looksok.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/sharedpreferences-not-saved-after-app-restart/).

Answer (score 0):

According to the document, the String Set in SharedPreferences should treated as immutable, things go south when trying to modify it. A work around would be:
Get the existing set, make a copy of it, update the copy and then save it back to the shared preferences like it was a new set.

```
Set<String> feedbackSet = getFeedbacksSet();
if(feedbackSet == null){
    feedbackSet = new HashSet<String>();
}

//make a copy of the set, update the copy and save the copy
Set<String> newFeedbackSet = new HashSet<String>();
JSONObject json = createJSONObjectfromFeedback(feedbackItem);
newFeedbackSet.add(json.toString());
newFeedbackSet.addAll(feedbackSet);
ed.putStringSet(CoreSetup.KEY_FEEDBACK, newFeedbackSet);
ed.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void saveFeedback(FeedbackItem feedbackItem) {
    checkSp();
    Set<String> feedbackSet = getFeedbacksSet();
    if(feedbackSet == null){
        feedbackSet = new HashSet<String>();
    }
    JSONObject json = createJSONObjectfromFeedback(feedbackItem);
    feedbackSet.add(json.toString());
    ed.putStringSet(CoreSetup.KEY_FEEDBACK, null);
    ed.commit();
    ed.putStringSet(CoreSetup.KEY_FEEDBACK, feedbackSet);
    ed.commit();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To save string in sharedprefernces

```
   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
   editor.putString("text", mSaved.getText().toString());
   editor.commit();
```

To retrieve data from shared preference

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
```

Comment: But I have a StringSet not just a String.

Comment: that means u have array list then do one thing use for loop and send string from first index to last index..

Comment: ? How should I store a set or list in a string? But anyway, the problem solved, the error was not related to your answer. But thank you for your comment.